# Concatenating multiple strings+stdouts into lolcat (in fish)

Tags: bash, shell, fish

I am trying to learn shell scripting, fish scripting in particular.
However, the question probably would be the same for bash.

What I am trying to accomplish is to concatenate a couple of strings with the stdout of screenfetch and put all of that into lolcat.

Right now I have the following:

```
screenfetch  -n | lolcat
set test "test"
echo $test | lolcat
```

This works, but lolcat is called two timesm thus the color scheme does not match. Performance wise it is bad code, too.

What I want to do is to concatenate the stdout from screenfetch with my $test variable and throw it at lolcat as one single package.

I could do something like this:

```
set sf (screenfetch -n)
set test "test"
set all $sf$test
echo $all | lolcat
```

But the stdout from screenfetch gets totally scrambled when stored into a var (formatting is lost).

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group your two commands and pipe the concatenated output to `lolcat`. The syntax for grouping commands differs between bash and fish:

```
# /bin/bash
{ screenfetch -n; echo "$test"; } | lolcat
```

```
# /usr/bin/fish
begin screenfetch -n; echo $test; end | lolcat
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.